# With AssemblyInfo.cs gone, where do I get my appid?

Tags: c#, .net-core, netsh

In the past, I would register the SSL cert of my application by running:

`netsh http add sslcert ipport=1.2.3.4:443 certhash=a4e9de3a1610ec4eae82fa81444061b8 appid={8792bd09737f8b48991bfce5c15f3700}`

Where the "appid" GUID came from the "assembly: Guid" attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs.
But with the new .Net Core applications, there is no AssemblyInfo.cs, so where do I get this appid from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place [assembly:] in any file you want. It could be for example Main.cs or any file you want (you can of course create file "AssemblyInfo.cs" to keep the convention from framework).

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. But is it ok to just generate my own GUID or is it supposed to match something else somewhere?

Comment: You can generate any GUID.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question...

I'm not sure if this is a wise thing to do, but I ended up creating my own AssemblyInfo.cs and populating it with a brand new assembly GUID.

It seems to work.